# What is the protocol used for authenticating/encrypting Mac-to-Mac screen sharing?

Tags: macos, authentication, encryption, protocols, vnc

The default Mac-to-Mac screen sharing uses VNC but obviously not the vanilla flavor as it uses both user+pass authentication (as opposed to password-only for regular VNC) as well as some encryption for the data.

What are these authentication and encryption protocols? Are there any libraries/modules/tools for Windows that support these protocols?

Answer (score 1):

according to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Concepts/Concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000976-CH203-TPXREF101) apple states that VNC supports Kerberos authentication. I don't know if any vanilla VNC clients support Kerberos authentication, but that may be a place to look.